# Serve content through CloudFront practically?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, cdn

I am developing a React app where users share paid/free digital content each other. I am using AWS CloudFront for CDN. Even though I learned a lot but in my case, I am still not sure what is the best practice to serve content. I need low latency and high transfer speed.

1. Is it practical to have 2 CloudFront distributions, one for downloadable paid/free content and one for static files (css, js if possible)?
2. Should I serve downloadable content through S3TA and static files through CloudFront?

To be honest, I don't want to use S3TA since people complaining about latency issues.

The first question might sound stupid but I want to keep caching time as low as possible (even disabled) for downloadable content. It is because of security concerns. Thus, I ask myself again, why not use S3TA instead?

Comment: You might want to look into [signed URLs and signed cookies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html).

Comment: I will be using signed URLs for downloadable content but what I am asking is different.

Comment: S3TA uses CloudFront in the background so no latency is not a difference but if you use your own cloudfront, you can modify settings as per your need which you can't do in S3TA. like lambda@edge , waf etc